# Links in navbar can't be clicked

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make this nav bar work in a way that I can send people to another page in the same website (I hope that makes sense)

My problem is that, links cannot be clicked, when I hover my mouse over the nav bar it just shows the text cursor, basically meaning that the site reads that line as just text instead of a clickable link; the submenu items, however, can be clicked.

This is the site, in case you want to see it for yourself: https://trenes.000webhostapp.com/

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<CENTER>
<FONT COLOR=#6c9200>
Seamos honestos, ¿hay algo mejor que los trenes en este mundo? No.<br>
</font>
</CENTER>
<TITLE>
ME GUSTAN LOS TRENES
</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<style>
<stlye type="text/css">
*{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#header{
margin:auto;
width:500px;
font-family:arial,helvetica,sand-serif;
}

ul,ol{
list-style:none;
}

.nav li a{
    background-color: #c8d0d7;
    color: #253051;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
}

.nav li a:hover{
background-color:#49657a;
}

.nav>li{
float:left;
}

.nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav li ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 140px;
}

.nav li ul li{
    position: relative;
}

.nav li ul li ul{
right:-180px;
top:0px;
}

</style>

<body>

<div id="header">
<ul class="nav">
<li> <a href"index.html">Inicio</a></li>
<li> <a href"imagenes.html">Imagenes</a></li>
<li> <a href"historia.hmtl">Historia</a></li>
<li> <a href"video.html">Videos</a>

<ul>
<li> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETfiUYij5UE" target="_blank">Thomas the dank engine</a></li>
<li> <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BpfLkR1EBI" target="_blank"> La importancia de los trenes en la economía</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have 2 html files so far, the index.html and imagenes.html uploaded to my webhost folder, I want to make it so when I click on "imagenes" on the navbar it takes me to imagenes.html file, just like it takes me to youtube when I click in one of the videos under "videos" submenu.

Thanks in advance!

Note: the 000webhost site doesn't support spanish characters so you'll see a lot of question marks, but don't mind that.

Comment: add the `=` sign after `href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just a little error - the missing `=` in your a href tags.

```
<a href="index.html" target="_self">Inicio</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href"index.html" target="_self">Inicio</a>
```

Comment: Holy cow! I never noticed that! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

use an equal sign after each href.
means use an = sign after href every time

Comment: Thanks! That was the very problem!